# Open Lookup Column hyperlink List Item in full window instead of modal dialog (SharePoint Online, Classic View)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, administration, classic-experience

I have several lists (task list, issue list, custom lists) with a lookup column to a different list.  The lookup column displays as a hyper link to the other list item.  However, when clicked it opens in a modal dialog, I would like for it to open in a full window instead.

Is there any way to do this?

Environment
SharePoint Online
Classic View

Comment: Go to the source list settings > advanced settings and turn Off open form in dialog option. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to lookup source/parent list (from where you have added lookup column)
2. Then go to List settings > Advanced settings
3. Set below option to "No"
4. Click OK to save the changes

[image]

Comment: Sorry, should have noted in my question that this setting is set to "No" in both the List being linked to and the List that has the lookup column.

Comment: You may be able to create a custom hyperlink using JSLink/Client side rendering (CSR) in classic experience for lookup column.